# What cause org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

What cause this exception, I can't manage to find out.

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of my.Class
```

Root cause:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of my.Class
```

Code:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public void setTags(Set<Tags> tags) {
    this.tags.clear();

    for (Tag tag : tags) {
        addTag(tag);
    }
}


public boolean addTag(final Tag tag) {
    if (tags.contains(tag)) {
        return false;
    }

    return tags.add(tag);
}
```

I initalize tags in the constructor:

```
tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
```

EDIT

Exception from logging in setter method:

```
ax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of com.mycompany.domain.Book.Tags
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:838) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:781) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:201304051638]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:201304051638]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:201304051638]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240) ~[spring-orm-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy215.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mycompany.persistence.BookJpaRepository.get(BookJpaRepository.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mycompany.service.BookService.getBook(BookService.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mycompany.service.BookService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d6b91ae6.invoke(<generated>) ~[BookService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d6b91ae6.class:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) ~[spring-tx-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631) ~[spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.service.BookService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e6a4e1a3.getBook(<generated>) ~[BookService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e6a4e1a3.class:na]
    at com.mycompany.rest.controller.BookController.getFeedbackForBook(BookController.java:106) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:201304051638]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:201304051638]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:201304051638]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) [javax.servlet-api.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770) [javax.servlet-api.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231) [web-core.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.50]
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.50]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0]
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of com.mycompany.domain.Book.Tags
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4499) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1103) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:960) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2111) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3917) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1091) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:174) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2473) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:987) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:807) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:201304051638]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:201304051638]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:201304051638]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getLoadedCollectionOwnerOrNull(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:859) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.AbstractCollectionEvent.getLoadedOwnerOrNull(AbstractCollectionEvent.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.InitializeCollectionEvent.<init>(InitializeCollectionEvent.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:549) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at com.mycompany.domain.Book.setTags(Book.java:185) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```

Comment: How are you initializing the `tags` member variable.  Is it possible that it's `null` and that an NPE is getting thrown when the setter is invoked?

Comment: Btw, annotate the setter is not supported in Jpa/Hibernate, instead annotate getter or field.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My guess is that Hibernate calls your setter with its own implementation of Set (PersistentSet) which implements lazy-loading, and is not initialized yet when the setter is called. Since you call a method on this set, it makes the set load itself while already being in a loading phase, which puts Hibernate in an inconsistent state.

That's why I prefer using field access over property access (i.e. put all the mapping annotations on fields rather than getters). You want to make a copy of the passed set when the method is called by "normal" code, but you don't want to do that when Hibernate itself calls the setter: it completely break lazy-loading.

Comment: In short : change your setter code to `this.tags = tags;`, and it should work fine.

Comment: We've done a very large project with field access strategy, we faced lots of troubles (but it is too late and it will costs us to much to change the strategy), because there is no way to override mappings in this strategy, but by overriding methods and re-annotating you can reconfigure mappings.

Comment: @JBNizet It works now, however is this a bad approach like Amir says?

Comment: @Amir: then you simply missed the [AttributeOverride(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) and [AssociationOverride(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AssociationOverride.html) annotations. No, using field access is not a bad approach at all.

Comment: +1 Helped a lot. It's not straightforward and exception gives no clue.

Answer (score 4):

From [javadoc](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/PropertyAccessException.html):

> A problem occurred accessing a property of an instance of a
>   persistent class by reflection, or via CGLIB. There are a number of
>   possible underlying causes, including
>
> ```
> - failure of a security check
> - an exception occurring inside the getter or setter method
> - a nullable database column was mapped to a primitive-type property
> - the Hibernate type was not castable to the property type (or vice-versa)
> ```

I would say, `this.tags`(field) or `tags`(parameter) is `null`, but in order to figure it out, you can print the entire stack-trace, tis would point the root cause.

Comment: Nope. It is initialized in the constructor.

Comment: Try to print tags at the setter time... because if your object is built based on deserialization, the constructor is not executed.

Comment: The correct way to figure this out is to wrap the internals of setTags in a try catch, and log any exceptions using your logging system of choice.

Comment: just to optimize it, you are using a `Set`, you don't need to check if the tag is already in the set, because a feature from `Set` is to have unique instances in it.

Comment: See exception, do you understand?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `null` as argument of method, so for-each construct throws an exception. Use a guard condition and everything goes ok:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public void setTags(Set<Tags> tags) {
    this.tags.clear();

    if (tags != null) {
        for (Tag tag : tags) {
            addTag(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

but I prefer:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public void setTags(Set<Tags> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily "you". Here Hibernate was calling my setter method passing a `null` argument and this threw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to figure this out is to wrap the internals of setTags in a try catch, and log any exceptions using your logging system of choice.

My first guess is that the tags instance variable is null. I would be very surprised if this wasn't the case, but it should be trivial to verify using a debugger in an integration test

My second guess would be that the argument passed to setTags() is not being initialized correctly, or is null, or is throwing some kind of exception when your for loop attempts to iterate on it.