# Many to One Mapping using Set

Tags: hibernate

I have two Table, supplier and company.

Companies will already be setup. While creating supplier, I will be getting a list of companies, to which supplier supplies the goods.

List will be of containing companies_id, which is primary key of company.
While inserting supplier details in supplier table, I want to Map the supplier to companies which he supllies in company Table.

I am doing this mapping in my SupplierEO

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = CompanyEO.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="Company_ID")
    public Set<CompanyEO> getCompanyEO() {
        return companyEO;
    }

public void setCompanyEO(Set<CompanyEO> companyEO) {
    this.companyEO = companyEO;
}
```

Am getting following error while saving supplier details

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException
>   occurred calling getter of CompanyEO.carrierId

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany`? Because if you have multiple `CompanyEO` in your `SupplierEO` you need to have a toMany relationship.
Also if you have multiple CompanyEOs please also call them like that. Calling a set of companies just company is misleadin, especially for someone who does not know your code.

Regarding your Exception: Please take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16124868/6505091).
Basically what [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) is saying is:

> My guess is that Hibernate calls your setter with its own implementation of Set (PersistentSet) which implements lazy-loading, and is not initialized yet when the setter is called. Since you call a method on this set, it makes the set load itself while already being in a loading phase, which puts Hibernate in an inconsistent state.

So it's better to use field access rather then property access.

Edit: Oh and also please add your whole stack trace, but rather as code and not as a blockquote.