# Eagerly loading a persistent object using hibernate annotations

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have three objects: A, B, and C.

A has a one-to-many relationship with B.

B has a one-to-many relationship with C.

The classes are as follow:

```
public class A {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(...)
   Set<B> getBSet();
}

public class B {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(...)
   Set<C> getCSet();
}
```

When I used session.get(A.class, id) (session is a Hibernate object and I already had the A instance saved in the database with one set of B and 1 set of C) to get a persistent object of class A with the provided id, I got the following exception:

```
Apr 12, 2018 4:44:25 PM org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener onLoad
INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of com.example.B.cSet
```

The setter in B is:

```
public void setCSet(Set<C> cSet) {
   this.cSet = cSet;
   ...
}
```

I thought I already forced everything to be eagerly loaded, but somehow it didn't work the way I wanted.

Any ideas what has happened and how should I fix it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move all annotations to fields instead of annotating methods. It looks like that annotating methods instead of fields breaks eager loading. Look at this question, looks similar to yours: [What cause org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124638/what-cause-org-hibernate-propertyaccessexception-exception-occurred-inside-sett)